# Cannot get <span> tags working inside hyperlinks

Tags: html, mysql, css

I'm using a simple database query to check roll stock from a product database.  I need the whole line to get bigger on hover (client request) so I can just make each of the individual columns separate hyperlinks. I hope I'm explaining this well enough.

I have used spans inside hyperlinks many times to format individual query results but this just isn't working.

The code I'm using:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

        // Get the id number of the roll from the array

            $id = $row['id'];

        echo '<a class="stock-results" href="************.php?id='.$id.'">'

            . '<span style="width:300px;">'.$row['rangename'].'</span>'.'<span width="300px">'.$row['rangecolour'].'</span>'.'</a>';

        echo '<br>';    

    };
```

There will be four columns ultimately, but initially just trying to get two to work.

I have tried adding the styling as a class, as a standard html width= and using inline `CSS` as shown.

I do get one long hyperlink with each of the columns, but its not recognizing the  tags to add the spacing I need.

Can anybody suggest a better way of achieving this?

Results of the above code ...

NATURAL BERBER ELISTECLUSRTER2.04M6.58M

Looking to achieve ...

NATURAL BERBER ELISTE   CLUSRTER    2.04M    6.58M

Comment: If that's a pure copy/paste, you've got a fatal typo `sapn`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<span>` elements are inline elements by default, so you can't give them a height or width. Try to assign `display: inline-block;` to these elements, then they will accept your width declaration.

Comment: Thank you, added the inline tags and worked straight away (despite the spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Typo error.  Replace your `</sapn>` with `</span>`

```
'<span style="width:300px;">'.$row['rangename'].'</sapn>'
```

Comment: This only true for the first span, the second one has a correct closing tag. Still, even correcting the spelling error won't solve the problem.

Comment: Quite right. I'd have (hopefully) spotted the typo eventually, but thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: I think you already got an answer from Paul, you have to change the display to inline-block.  Sorry I didn't read your entire post, I just noticed the typo so I posted it.

Comment: Don't worry.  If you hadn't have pointed it out I would have tried the answer from Paul and it still wouldn't have worked despite being the the correct answer ..... So I thank you, it saved me precious time debugging a silly mistake.